# Swift Sprite Kit: How do I make it so that iAd displays a new add after a certain time interval?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I implemented iAd into my swift sprite kit application, but want to make it so that iAd displays a new ad every minute for example.  I supplied my code for how I implemented iAd below.

```
 self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
}


func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {

    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveWithError error:NSError!) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html) for that. Keep in mind that if your app goes into background mode, it may cause some inaccuracies. However since it's only for showing ads, it's shouldn't be a big issue.

Comment: How would i go about using NSTimer in this situation?